# Deserializing a byte[] back into a DataTable

Tags: c#, serialization, datatable, binary-serialization

I have the following code to serialize /deserialize a DataTable:

```
    public static byte[] Serialize(DataTable dt)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, dt); 
        return stream.GetBuffer(); 
    }


    public static DataTable Deserialize(byte[] buffer) 
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer);
        System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        return formatter.Deserialize(stream) as DataTable; 
    }
```

The serialize method works fine but the deserialize method produces this error:

```
  The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 1F-8B-08 ...
```

I am 99% sure I have gotten this method to work in the past, not sure whats wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you are giving the exact output of `Serialize` to `Deserialize`? try running `Deserialize(Serialize(object))` and see if it errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not use `GetBuffer()` but `ToArray()` since the latter returns really the content while `Getbuffer()` could return uninitialized bytes...

see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx